# Way to escape or at-least detect in-app browsers

Tags: browser-detecting

Is there a generic way to detect and preferably escape from in-app browsers like the ones used by Facebook, Twitter and some news apps.

We are running an add-campaign on both Facebook and a common dutch news site.

In both cases people end up in my web-app with limited browsers, not allowing people to upload a picture for-example.

I'd like to give these people a simple option to escape from the handicapped in-app browser.

I did find this for detecting on IOS . . but not really anything on Android.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These in-app browsers are basically a cut down version of the native browser and so have the same user agent string. Unfortunately there is no way strictly speaking to detect them and break out of them as the apps (such as the facebook app) will always open the links using the in-app browser instead of closing the app and opening up the complete browser app. The only thing I can suggest is using javascript to check and see if the feature you are trying to use is available in the browser before presenting it to the end user. You can take a look at http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/detect.html which shows how to use Modernizr to check if certain HTML5 features are supported in the users browser which can be used to switch off unsupported features on your site.